# Do OpenGL immediate mode functions work in MacBook air M1 environment?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake

Hi I am one unlucky student who uses M1 MacBook Air 2020 in Computer Graphics class in University.

Since the class is based on Windows environment, the class uses WinAPI and Windows' OpenGL stuffs. As I search, Apple stopped supporting OpenGL in OSX environment so the latest version I can use is OpenGL 4.1.

The problem is sample code the professor uploaded has `glBegin() ... glEnd()` kind of immediate mode function and some others. (`glColor3f(), glLoadIdentity()`). I tried to setup that sample code in CLion with CMake, with `GLFW, GLAD`. And it won't compile because compiler cannot find those functions I mentioned up there.

The compiler error message

```
main.cpp:14:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'glBegin'
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
// and all the other functions in DrawTriangle()
```

Everything else works fine and compiles without problem, functions like `glGenBuffer(), glBindBuffer()`.

Q. Can I make this work or is it not supposed to work anymore in my MacBook?

---

Here are my CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp

CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(demo src/main.cpp)

include_directories(demo glad-3.1/include)

add_library(glad glad-3.1/src/glad.c)

find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(demo
        fmt::fmt
        OpenGL::GL
        glad
        glfw
)

if(APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(demo
            "-framework Cocoa"
            "-framework OpenGL"
            "-framework IOKit")
endif()
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
// Defined before OpenGL and GLUT includes to avoid deprecation messages
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#endif

#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <iostream>

// Won't Compile!!
void DrawTriangle()
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-10.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(10.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 20.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}

void PrintShaderCompilationLog(GLuint shader)
{
    // prints compilation log...
}

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *win = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "demo", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    const GLubyte *renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const GLubyte *ver = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    std::cout << "Renderer : " << renderer << '\n';
    std::cout << "Ver : " << ver << std::endl;

    const char *vertexShaderSource =
        "#version 410 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\0";

    GLuint vertShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);

    glCompileShader(vertShader);
    PrintShaderCompilationLog(vertShader);

    const char *fragShaderSource =
        "#version 410 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
        "}\0";

    GLuint fragShader = 0;
    fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, &fragShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragShader);
    PrintShaderCompilationLog(fragShader);

    GLuint program = 0;
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    glUseProgram(program);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  // A
        0.5f,  -0.5f,  // B
        0.0f,  0.5f    // C
    };

    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                          (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(win))
    {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(win);
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(win);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine if I comment out `DrawTriangle()` which the sample code uses instead.

---

I tried with multiple version of [GLAD](https://glad.dav1d.de/), with GL version 3.1 (that seems to work with immediate mode according to [gl docs](https://docs.gl/gl3/glLoadIdentity)) but seems not compiling, with the same `undeclared identifier` compiler error.

---

### Update

I found out `glad` is not necessary since I could just use `OpenGL/gl.h` instead, and those old functions (`glBegin(), glColor3f()...` compiles and works fine.

If I log which OpenGL version is being used, it says `Version 2.1`. This is without setting `glfwWindowHint()` variables `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR/MINOR, GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE`.

If I set those variables like this, GLFW won't create window and returns a null window.

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

The one [search result in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GraphicsProgramming/comments/1482win/comment/jnytohl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) I found is MacOS in 2024 has OpenGL 2.1 compatibility profile(?) and 4.1 core profile since deprecated.

As a conclusion,

- I think I can work on class sample codes without `glad`
- I need to include `OpenGL/gl.h` (not `OpenGL/gl3.h`)
- I have to work on with OpenGL version 2.1 since 4.1 core profile won't support removed functions.

Comment: "And it won't compile because compiler cannot find those functions I mentioned up there." - Do not *describe* the error message. Instead, paste the error message into the question post **exactly as it is**.

Comment: Oopsie sorry newbie mistake, fixed it.

Comment: Yes, "core profile" literally means "not the old crap your professor is teaching you".